# How Get Other Value from select option ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I have something like this
.html

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label>Choose Industry Type</ion-label>
    <ion-select (ionChange)="getOuterName()" [(ngModel)]="getSelectedValue">
        <ion-option *ngFor="let some of someItems" value="{{some.id}}">
            {{some.name}} </ion-option>
    </ion-select>
</ion-item>
<p>{{getSelectedValue}}</p>
```

.ts

```
someItems = [{'id': 1, 'name':'Agriculture','othervalue':'123'},
          {'id': 2, 'name':'Chemicals','othervalue':'1234'},
          {'id': 3, 'name':'Pesticides','othervalue':'12345'}];
getOuterName(){
 console.log(this.getSelectedValue);
 let term = this.someItems.filter(item => item.othervalue ===this.getSelectedValue );
}
```

can i get **'othervalue'** to show in **'getSelectedValue'** without changing **value="{{some.id}}"** in ion-option ?

Comment: so what value does is show now? because you have used ngModel, it should show the value.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is just bind the whole object into `value`

html:-

```
<ion-item>
        <ion-label>Choose Industry Type</ion-label>
        <ion-select (ionChange)="getOuterName()" [(ngModel)]="getSelectedValue"  >
            <ion-option *ngFor="let some of someItems" [value]="some" >
                {{some.name}} </ion-option>
        </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
```

in .ts:-

```
 someItems = [{'id': 1, 'name':'Agriculture','othervalue':'123'},
          {'id': 2, 'name':'Chemicals','othervalue':'1234'},
          {'id': 3, 'name':'Pesticides','othervalue':'12345'}];

getOuterName(){
// Your can call your **this.getSelectedValue** and its properties
 console.log( this.getSelectedValue.id + this.getSelectedValue.name);

 let term = this.someItems.filter(item => item.othervalue ===this.getSelectedValue.othervalue );
}
```

this way you can have both `id` and `othervalue`

Comment: I got this :

/turbo_modules/@angular/compiler@5.2.9/bundles/compiler.umd.js (528:34)
Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'value' since it isn't a known property of 'ion-select-option'.
1. If 'ion-select-option' is an Angular component and it has 'value' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ion-select-option' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

Comment: iam sorry, that was my mistake i work on ionic 4 so tested code on that and in ionic 4 we use ```ion-select-option``` rather than ```ion-option```(ionic 3 varient). just use ```ion-option``` and it will work. i updated the code above as well.